# Can't fetch city data from from geonames api using the city name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I'm creating a simple web app to fetch city data from geonames api with the url : http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON

But when I get the data back its an empty array. I have tried the api in postman and directly in the browser and get the correct result. But not from the app. Right now I'm just console.logging the data so you might have to check the console for this. The app is made by using node and express server.

my server.js:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path')

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors())
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static(path.join('application')));
app.get("/all", function sendData(req, res) {
    res.send(projectData);
})

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    projectData['temp'] = req.body.temp;
    projectData['date'] = req.body.date;
    projectData['content'] = req.body.content;
    res.send(projectData);
})

// Setup Server
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
    console.log("Go to http://localhost:8080")
})
```

my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form id="userInfo">
            <label for="city">Enter city</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
            <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

my app.js:

```
const username = "demo";
const baseURL = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON"


const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = document.getElementById("city");
    if (city !== "") {
        getCoords(username, city, baseURL)
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Invalid zipcode");

            })
    }
})

const getCoords = async (username, city, baseURL) => {

    // res equals to the result of fetch function
    const res = await fetch(`${baseURL}?q=${city}&username=${username}`);
    try {

        // data equals to the result of fetch function
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use your browser's developer tools (e.g. F12 in Chrome Windows) to see if the URL actually the same or not.  You can see all the headers and everything.  This is just a HTTP GET request, so you can easily just type the URL into the browser and see the request (don't need postman or anything).  Compare a successful request to an unsuccessful request (they're both coming from the browser) and see what's different between the requests.  There must be something different.

Comment: Ok so when I hard-coded the city name in the string literal in my app.js the code works... but not when I enter the city name in the submit form... in that case it returns an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the city element object as the value to the query instead of the actual `value` property of the element.

You should replace this line:

```js
const city = document.getElementById("city");
```

With this one:

```js
const city = document.getElementById("city").value;
```

While passing the element object to the query, as per the JS rules of conversion, it will be converted into the string '[object HTMLInputElement]':

`http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=[object%20HTMLInputElement]&username=demo`

**Tip:** make it a habit to `console.log` the actual value that you are passing to a function call in order to make sure that you are passing the correct value. For example, instead of:

```js
const res = await fetch(`${baseURL}?q=${city}&username=${username}`);
```

Double check the value that you are passing to `fetch` via a simple `console.log`:

```js
const URL = `${baseURL}?q=${city}&username=${username}`;
console.log("URL:", URL); // <= Am I seeing the correct value?
const res = await fetch(URL);
```

Also, as `Wyck` mentioned, make good use of the powerful `Network Tab` to get a good look at what's happening between the client and the server:

[image]

Comment: @RohanAsif, if you had used your developer tools to inspect the query you would have been able to see that it was fetching `http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=[object%20HTMLInputElement]&username=demo`.  Please do this basic kind of investigation next time before asking a question.